# How can I force mapped drive synchronization in MS Windows XP?

Tags: vbscript

I searched, so hopefully this isn't already a posted question already.

Basically, when we have users connect to the network via VPN, even though the login script will run and map their network drives, their home share drive (in this case P:) does not reflect the network version and shows the "offline" version.

The problem is they don't see all their files, and of course don't know how to trigger synchronization.  Of course ideally we would just turn it off and there would be no problem, but as most of you know, working in a corporate environment we're bound by the decisions of the guys in another department.

So, is there a way to trigger folder synchronization? OR is there a way to force Windows when mapping the drive to look to the network version?  I tried the true switch on the mapnetworkdrive method of the WSHnetwork but no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple solution, you can call "mobsync.exe /logon", closing thread.

Details from [microsoft](http://search.microsoft.com/results.aspx?form=MSHOME&mkt=en-us&setlang=en-us&q=mobsync.exe), their pages move around so this is just a search.

Comment: Some documentation about the /logon option would be helpful. I don't see how it "forces" a sync.